# django how to use AUTH_PROFILE_MODULE with multiple profiles?

Tags: python, django, django-models

Assuming I have different profiles for different user types - staff, teacher,students:

How do I specify `AUTH_PROFILE_MODULE` in order to get back the appropriate profile with `get_profile`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There no way to do that but you could use the generic key.

```
from django.contrib.contenttypes import generic
from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType

class UserProfileOne(models.Model):
    pass

class UserProfileTwo(models.Model):
    pass


class UserProfile(models.Model):
    content_type    = models.ForeignKey(ContentType)
    object_id       = models.PositiveIntegerField(db_index=True)
    content_object  = generic.GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')
```

Example:

```
UserProfile.objects.create(content_object=any_profile_instance)

User(pk=1).get_profile().content_object.some_special_field
```

If you could provide more infos, when it might be possible to find a better solution :)

Answer (score 0):

It may be more hassle to try to use multiple profiles with the simplistic configuration of UserProfile.

I would suggest using UserProfile with generic foreign key, or completely ditch UserProfile and create separate models with a User foreign key.

If you are going to have a lot of data attached to these extra user profiles, I would keep them in models separate from UserProfile.  My personal opinion about UserProfile is that it can quickly become the dumping ground for user data that doesn't have a nice home.

Don't think that you have to use UserProfile just because your data sounds like it is profile information.  I don't think UserProfile was ever intended to solve all the problems. I see it as a way to make up for the fact that the code for the User model is under django code and we don't generally mess with it to add user data.